# Can't set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header for REST API

Tags: rest, aws-amplify

I'm having the following issues:

1. I need to allow CORS only on a specific domain
2. I need to make sure that secure cookies are sent along with the cross-origin request.

API Gateway specifies '*' as the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and I need to only allow "example.com".

I found that I can do this by adding the following in `override.ts` in the rest API resource folder:

```js
import { AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';

export function override(resources: AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate) {
  // Change the default CORS response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin from "'*'" to the API's domain
  resources.restApi.body.paths['/v1'].options['x-amazon-apigateway-integration'].responses.default.responseParameters['method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = { 
    'Fn::Sub': "'https://www.example.com'" 
  };
}
```

This seems unreasonably hacky, but whatever.

But I can't seem to solve for the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header... This doesn't work:

```js
import { AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';

export function override(resources: AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate) {

  // Change the default CORS response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin from "'*'" to the API's domain
  resources.restApi.body.paths['/v1'].options['x-amazon-apigateway-integration'].responses.default.responseParameters['method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = { 
    'Fn::Sub': "'https://www.example.com'" 
  };

  // ADDING THIS ...

  resources.restApi.body.paths['/v1'].options['x-amazon-apigateway-integration'].responses.default.responseParameters['method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "true";

}
```

I get multiple errors, but it's basically complaining with this error for each of my REST endpoints:

```
Unable to put integration response on 'OPTIONS' for resource at path '/oauth/hubspot': Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: true]
```

I get similar errors if I try any of the following:

```
// with quotes inside quotes
  resources.restApi.body.paths['/v1'].options['x-amazon-apigateway-integration'].responses.default.responseParameters['method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = "'true'";
```

```
// this structure
  resources.restApi.body.paths['/v1'].options['x-amazon-apigateway-integration'].responses.default.responseParameters['method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = { 
    'Fn::Sub': "'true'" 
  };
```

The thing is, I could easily do all this myself if Amplify would just let me override how I handle the OPTIONS request, and send it to my lambda function....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VICTORY!

I'd still be interested in any suggested approaches, but this worked for me:

```js
// This file is used to override the REST API resources configuration
import { AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';

export function override(resources: AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate) {
  delete resources.restApi.body.paths['/v1'].options;
  delete resources.restApi.body.paths['/v1/{proxy+}'].options;
}
```

Basically, it's me telling Amplify to get out of the way and let me handle the OPTIONS request myself. So this leaves the "ANY" method on the endpoint so that the OPTIONS request flows through to the LAMBDA that's already configured. I already had the code in there to handle OPTIONS requests, so... It. Just. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been six months since you asked this question, but it's something i've just been smashing my head against now.

I had exactly the same issue:

1. I need CORS across several domains, but I can't use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` because in the browser I am calling the api with `{ withCredentials: true }`.
2. My Api's back into a lambda function which correctly handles the CORS preflight on the `OPTION` request. (ie. it returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://permitted.origin.goes.here` and associated headers).

But I get CORS errors because the AWS API Gateway response for `OPTION` is using a predefined MOCK response, which does not allow any other value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` than `'*'`.
(this was all generated by Amplify).

Anyways, I tried your method of deleting the `OPTION` handler, but that still did not work for me.

Eventually, after configuring it correctly in the AWS API Gateway interface, exporting the swagger and replicating that in the `override.ts` file, I finally got it cleanly working.

this was my code in `override.ts`:

```
import { AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate } from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';

export function override(resources: AmplifyApiRestResourceStackTemplate) {

   const { paths } = resources.restApi.body;

   Object.keys(paths).forEach((path) => {
      if (!!paths[path].options) {
         const uri = paths[path]['x-amazon-apigateway-any-method']['x-amazon-apigateway-integration'].uri;                  
         paths[path].options = {
            "responses" : {
              "200" : {
                "description" : "200 response",
                "headers" : {
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
              "httpMethod" : "POST",
              "uri" : uri,
              "responses" : {
                "default" : {
                  "statusCode" : "200"
                }
              },
              "passthroughBehavior" : "when_no_match",
              "contentHandling" : "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
              "type" : "aws_proxy"
            }
         }
      }
   });
}
```

Now I can return secure cookies to a browser app from the AWS REST API without choking on CORS errors.

good luck!